# ContextMenuCreated Event on Monodroid

Tags: android, dialog, contextmenu, xamarin.android

I want to create a context menu within a dialog and im trying to use this event ContextMenuCreated from the List View control. So i create the context menu with that but i want to know how can i delegate methods to those menu items that I've created. This is the code:

```
dialogFilter.RegisterForContextMenu(listView);

        listView.ContextMenuCreated += delegate(object sender, CreateContextMenuEventArgs e) {
            e.Menu.SetHeaderTitle("Options");
            e.Menu.Add(0,1,1,"Edit");
            e.Menu.Add(0,2,1,"Delete");
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "methods". You mean being able to click a menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
public override void OnCreateContextMenu(IContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    base.OnCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.SetHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.Add(0,1,1,"Edit");
    menu.Add(0,2,1,"Delete");
}

public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, item.TitleFormatted, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: those override methods inherits from Activity, and im doing my own control, extending from LinearLayout, and i cant override OnContextitemselected Method, so im asking if is another way to do it?